# How do I control users balances from an external contract?

Tags: erc-20, balances, wallet-transfer

I'm developing a blockchain project where I have two separate contracts, the ERC20 token contract and the Main one that contains the application logic. 
I need to be able to move users' tokens as I like from the main contract without having them do anything. How can I control users balances from the external contract?

Thank you a lot, I'm new to Ethereum developing and trying to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create a function in contracts which burns the tokens from current contract and another function which updates the token in mapping.

Keep the function only admin accessible, and call the functions.

Comment: Alternatively, just have the allowance for everyone from the main contract be unlimited, so it can always do a `transferFrom`